# Auto Generate Documentation based on FluentValidator written

Tags: c#, swagger, fluentvalidation, documentation-generation

is there a way to generate documentation based on FluentValidator that has been written for request?
I need information like: the field is `NotEmpty(), MaximumLength(40)`, etc.

Please direct me

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I mean to get validations that a certain filed have. So if validator looks like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .NotEmpty()
            .EmailAddress()
            .MaximumLength(30);
        RuleFor(x => x.Password)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MinimumLength(ValidationConstants.MinLength)
            .MaximumLength(ValidationConstants.MaxLengthPassword)
```

I want to get that 1st field has to be Not Empty with Maximum Length 30 and so on

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more information about what you mean by "documentation"? What is the use case for this documentation?

Comment: That's better, but can you add more information about the use case for this documentation, and what you would like for output? HTML? PDF? JSON?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've read about OpenAPI, but hoped there is something with FluentValidation..

Comment: So you are trying to generate documentation for Swagger? I'm still unsure what you are asking for.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, for Swagger

Comment: I am not familiar with Swagger and its API, but I added the [tag:swagger] and [tag:documentation] tags to your question. Hopefully that will trigger someone with more experience with Swagger to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such feature. `FluentValidator` only generates error messages for the validations.

If relevant, the error message can be used in the response body of the request, along with a `400 Bad Request` status code.